# How to fix Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin has been blocked by CORS policy in nuxtjs?

Tags: vue.js, authentication, axios, nuxt.js

[request payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QALPf.png)

iam using nuxt-auth module and using API for get the token , but i got an error about CORS Policy , what should i do ?

i've try another API for login and success . I got error like this

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://blablabla.co.id/index.php/api_users/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

this is my nuxt.config.js :

```
axios: {
 baseURL: 'http://blablabla.co.id/index.php'
},
auth: {
 redirect: {
  login: '/login',
  home: '/mainmap',
  logout: '/login'
},
strategies: {
  local: {
    endpoints: {
      login: {
        url: '/api_users/login',
        method: 'post',
        propertyName: 'token'
      },
      logout: false
    }
  }
},
token: {
  name: 'token'
},
cookie: {
  name: 'token'
}
```

and my login component:

```
async login () {
    try {
      await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
        data: {
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password
        }
      })

      this.$router.push('/')
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.response)
      this.error = e.response.data.error
    }
  }
```

Response from API is

> {"status_code":400,"status_text":"BAD REQUEST","error":["username field is required","password field is required"]}

i've debug and username and password is doesnt empty, so anyone can help with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using axios proxy module?

Comment: There are two ways.
See the link to determine how you applied it to your project.

1. When using the Axios module
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1679

2. When using a Nuxtj.s Axios module
https://github.com/nuxt-community/proxy-module

If you use the proxy option in axios, you can send the request from http://localhost:3000 to  http://blablabla.co.id/index.php/api_users/login.

Answer (score 0):

The response doesn't show any Error like CORS. The response status code is 400. If it was a CORS error you will get the error on the HTTP side only.

Please check your request payload. If possible please post the screenshot of the request payload.

Comment: thats it , i dont get the request payload